# Firebase has not been correctly initialized in Dart app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I've created a number of apps (beginner) including Firebase, Firestore without an issue. Now I'm struggling with a new project to get the Firebase initialisation working. Running out of ideas.
Developing on Mac, Android Studio for IoS and Android.

Error:
Firebase has not been correctly initialized.
Usually this means you've attempted to use a Firebase service before calling `Firebase.initializeApp`.`

```
Main
WidgetsFlutterBinding .ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
runApp(const MyApp());

android/build.gradle (extracts)
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14"
}

android/settings.gradle
plugins {
id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.0" apply false
}

app/build.gradle
plugins {
id "com.android.application"
id "kotlin-android"
id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}
defaultConfig {
applicationId "xxx"
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName
multiDexEnabled true
}

pubspec
environment:
sdk: '\>=3.1.4 \<4.0.0'
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
firebase_core: ^2.20.0
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_lints: ^3.0.0
flutter:
uses-material-design: true`
```

different firebase core versions

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I downgraded from 4.4.0 to 4.3.12 but reverted back to 4.4.0. All in synch - no difference

Comment: I have this exact same problem in my Flutter app now too, did you ever solve it?

Comment: Ah I wonder if the config plist file has not been added to the Xcode project... yes that was it :)

Comment: `flutter clean`

Answer (score 0):

In your `main.dart`'s `main` function, put this:

```dart
 await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

It should be called *before* utilizing anything Firebase related.

Comment: I already have it.

Comment: void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding .ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();   runApp(const MyApp());
}

Comment: in method_channel_firebase.dart, both the defaultApp and _options are Null. Should the defaultApp be Null?       

if (defaultApp == null && _options == null) {
        throw coreNotInitialized();
      }

Comment: I'm not a native Android dev, apologies, I just know that this is what the FlutterFire docs specify to do.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Very frustrating. I've had a lot of experience in OOP/C++/embedded programming but this is a different world with poor/out of date documentation.

Comment: Anyone? any other suggestions?
Firebase has not been correctly initialized.

Usually this means you've attempted to use a Firebase service before calling `Firebase.initializeApp`.

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the Firebase config plist file to the Xcode project

[image]